# Are there any naming conventions for command line arguments?

Tags: java, command-line, cross-platform, case-sensitive, conventions

I'm reviewing a command line driven Java application with command line switches in lower camel case like this:

```
myapp aSwitch anotherSwitch aThirdSwitch
```

Am thinking all lower case and leading hyphens may be preferable:

```
myapp -aswitch -anotherswitch -athirdswitch
```

...or perhaps:

```
myapp -a-switch -another-switch -a-third-switch
```

... or maybe:

```
myapp --a-switch --another-switch --a-third-switch
```

...but struggling to come up with a compelling justification. Would like to follow current conventions and be cross-platform compatible, at least for Windows/Linux.

Seeking some advice on what is the most commonly used convention out of these - and any reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Apache Commons CLI](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) has a description of the commonly used convention.  it is also a good parser for such use cases

Answer (score 0):

I work mostly on linux, but the usual is

```
app -<option1> <option1 value> -<option2> <option2 value> -<option2> <option3 value>
```

If every option has a value or parameter to pass

```
myapp -o1 aSwitch -o2 anotherSwitch -o3 aThirdSwitch
```

Comment: Thanks - actually the arguments for this particular app don't have values - they just change the nature of what it does. (I guess they are akin to `ls -l` or similar.)

Comment: Well then if you are working on a CLI application, i'd just list them like this

    

myapp -aSwitch -anotherSwitch -aThirdSwitch



and given a wrong input, print a formatting help with the options it supports or something similar